# How do you categorize pages?

Tags: categories, widgets

I am an experienced Drupal developer who is just getting stuck into Wordpress.

For a selected number of pages on a new wordpress build, I need to add them into a category, then add this category block to a page that shows the different categories (selecting them will act as a filter).

In drupal this would involve create a custom content type, a taxonomy and a views block etc.

How can the same be achieved in wordpress?

I know that I can create a sidebar and drop a widget into it. But I am struggling to workout how to create the block to drop into there and categorize these pages.

Answer (score 1):

You will only need a one basic function for the taxonomy, it's really straightforward: [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

If you want to use a custom post type, it's just as simple: [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

For the widget, it's a little more complicated. You'll need to look at how to register widgets, and saving values and such. All of that is covered in [Justin Tadlock's EXCELLENT tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/26/the-complete-guide-to-creating-widgets-in-wordpress-28). You'll also probably need to look into [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to query the posts, taxonomies and such.

That should get you going, if you have any specific issues implementing any of that, it's probably better served in a separate question that defines the scope of your question more...well...specifically! :)